# curl with login not working bash

Tags: html, bash, curl

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to connect to a website using curl with a login and possibly cookies.

Here is the auth html of the site:

```
<div id="authorize">

<form action="/" method="post" id="user-login" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="my-form-wrapper">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
<input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />  <label class="option" for="edit-name">E-mail Address <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

<div class="description">Please enter your E-mail Address.</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
<input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />  <label class="option" for="edit-pass">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

<div class="description">Enter your Password.</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-Jrv1EcWkN7AHVeYQoKEGjmtx5OSIcfcS7BbLp4vPB7k" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login" />
<div class="login-forgot"><a href="/user/password">Forgot?</a></div><input type="hidden" name="dest_page" value="/home" />
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="form-submit" /></div></div></div></form>                  
        <div class="register"><a href="/user/register">Register</a></div>


</div>
```

I thought the correct data to pass would be something like this:

(For this example my email = `myname@email.com` and my password = `mypass!`)

```
curl -d "name=myname%40email.com&pass=mypass%21&form_build_id=form-Jrv1EcWkN7AHVeYQoKEGjmtx5OSIcfcS7BbLp4vPB7k&form_id=user_login&dest_page=%2Fhome&op=Log+in" https://mywebsite.com
```

Two problems I run into.

1) Each time I `curl` the site, it produces a new `form_build_id`

2) I can't tell if my login is working, and am I supposed to convert `@` to `%40` and `!` to `%21` for my username and password?

Comment: "Each time I curl the site, it produces a new form_build_id." That's to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do. :)

Comment: `form_build_id` is likely `CSRF`/etc. protection so you are quite likely going to need to fetch and reflect that back to the server. As to the rest I don't know. Try it in a browser and find out what it sends?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I was really hoping there was a way around it... :/

Comment: There likely is -- you just have to do like Etan suggested. Grab the page once, parse the id out of it, then resubmit with that id. Can't do that with just curl though. (And you may have to reflect cookies back as well.)

Comment: @AlexHowansky I've tried this method, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I've never successfully accomplished passing cookies, so I can't tell if it's working. And also it sometimes changes from post to get or there's a redirect or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Get token and construct the cookie, save the returned token.

```
token=$(curl -b $cookie_path -c $cookie_path --request GET "$site_url/services/session/token" -s)
```

## Authentication. POST to $login_url with the token in header "X-CSRF-Token: $token".

```
curl -H "X-CSRF-Token: $token" -b $cookie_path -c $cookie_path -d "username=$username&password=$password" "$login_url" -s
```

## Get new token after authentication.

```
token=$(curl -b $cookie_path -c $cookie_path --request GET "$site_url/services/session/token" -s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool that can do the parsing/request building/resending in a single call, you can use my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel https://mywebsite.com -f 'form((//form)[1], {"name": "myname", "pass": "mypass"})' --download -
```